# Run a custom powershell docker image via docker compose

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose

I created a custom docker image to have a `poweshell` with `Ansible` already installed on it.

Hi created my image with a docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ansible
```

I built the image with the command:

`PS D:\Projects\ansible> docker build -t ansible-image .`

I see in Docker desktop that the image has been built correctly:

[image]

Now I want to run my image in another project and in this case I want to use `docker compose`. I use `docker compose` because I already know I will extend my project with other containers. I am just running one container a time just to verify everithing is ok.

Here my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
    powershell-ansible:
        image: ansible-image
        container_name: ansible-powershell
        restart: always
        stdin_open: true 
        tty: true
```

And here the command I use to run the container:

`PS D:\Projects\sre> docker compose up`

The container starts:
[image]

But it's like I cannot use the Powershell:

[image]

There is nothing other what you see in the latter image. I cannottype anything.

What's wrong in what I am doing?

Thank you.